# Textfiled input error alert in Sproutcore

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

There are some text fields in my Sproutcore code. However, I need to check the input validation for the text field.

Are there any mechanisms which I can do that like in traditional html/js? Could you please attach some code? Thanks.

Currently I just use the alert().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `SC.TextFieldView`, you can use Validator. Here is an example:

```
SC.TextFieldView.design({              
  validator: 'Number', 
  maxLength: 20,
}),
```

You can create your own validators to feet your needs. For examples and documentation, take a look at :

```
sproutcore/frameworks/foundation/validators
```

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a nice way to display the validation errors, checkout `SC.AlertPane`. It has `.info()`, `.error()`, and `.warning()` methods which will configure and open a nice looking pane to display the validation errors.